# TypeError: 'DataFrameReader' object is not callable

Tags: python, csv, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using PySpark to read a csv file.
Below is my simple code.

```
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession

def predict_metrics():
    session = SparkSession.builder.master('local').appName("PredictFacebookMetrics").getOrCreate()
    dataframe = session.read().format('com.databricks.spark.csv') \
        .option('header', True) \
        .option('delimiter', ';') \
        .option('inferSchema', True) \
        .load(r'D:\M\Facebook_metrics_data\dataset_Facebook.csv')
    dataframe.printSchema()
    dataframe.show(False)

if __name__=='__main__':
    predict_metrics()
```

Upon executing above code I get the following error:

`TypeError: 'DataFrameReader' object is not callable`

What is the solution to this error?

Comment: It is `session.read.format....`  instead of `session.read().format..` :)

Comment: Yes, that did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As suggested in comment, 
It should be `session.read.format` instead of `session.read().format`

Silly Me!